# Copy complete Html-page to the clipboard

Tags: c#, html, clipboard

In my c# app, I am generating html which is used to visualize data, In order to copy it to the clipboard. I found lots of links explaining how to copy html to the clipboard, but they all talk about coping fragments, not complete html documents.

I followed this [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767917(v=vs.85).aspx) and experimented with the numbers inside description, but failed to copy my complete html also without copying the description part. i need the html to to paste it for example into an email to get a well formatted text.

so can anyone please tell me what's the most easy way to solve this problem?

EDIT:

i talk about a desktop app and this is how i generate the html i want to copy to the clipboard (-1 is just an example. i tried lots of other numbers instead):

```
        var htmlHeader = new StringBuilder();
        htmlHeader.Append("Version:0.9 ");
        htmlHeader.Append("StartHTML:-1 ");
        htmlHeader.Append("EndHTML:-1 ");
        htmlHeader.Append("StartFragment:-1 ");
        htmlHeader.Append("EndFragment:-1 ");
        htmlHeader.Append("StartSelection:-1 ");
        htmlHeader.Append("EndSelection:-1 ");
        htmlHeader.Append("<!DOCTYPE> ");
        var mainHtmlString = "<html><body style='background-color: #E5EDFF;'>" +        contentTasks + contentContacts + "<body></html>";
        Clipboard.SetText(htmlHeader.ToString() + mainHtmlString, TextDataFormat.Html);
```

Comment: What kind of application is it? Desktop? Web? Are you storing the generated HTML to a string or retrieving to a stream?

Comment: its a desktop app. i just create a stringBuilder with the html i need and then call Clipboard.SetText(html.ToString() , TextDataFormat.Html). i just need to generate the html to copy it to the clipboard and then paste it for example into an email.

Answer (score 0):

I am making few assumptions from your question ,(i.e) You have a desktop C# application that needs to get the contents of a HTML Page and parse it in the C# application. If so then the code would be

```
using System.Net;

WebClient client = new WebClient ();
string reply = client.DownloadString (address); /* address is the complete URL as string */
```

The variable `reply` can be parsed as required.

Comment: sorry for my unclear description. i edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the string saved as HTML text, remove the TextDataFormat parameter, or set it to text. If you want actual HTML data saved to it, check out this post: http://theartofdev.com/2014/06/12/setting-htmltext-to-clipboard-revisited/.

Instead of just setting the clipboard to a text string, you have to create a DataObject and set that, so that whatever receives the data can read the piece it supports.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you can right click the page in your favorite browser and view-source and copy the complete page HTML code there. But there is a gotcha! with this approach. Both **Google** and **Firefox** ***view-source*** modes will wrap the page HTML code in line numbers. In the clipboard buffer the line numbers is actually a html wrapper code, which you will have to strip out. IE does not do this.

```
//Firefox Paste from source view
//<!--StartFragment--><pre id="line1"><span></span><span class="doctype"><!DOCTYPE html></span><span>
                    //<span id="line2"></span>


//Google Chrome paste from source view
//<!--StartFragment--><table style="letter-spacing: normal; orphans: auto; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; widows: 1; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px;"><tbody><tr><td class="line-number" value="1"><!DOCTYPE html></td><td class="line-content">
```